# How do I efficiently declare AngularJS module dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module, dependencies

I have an Angular application which is going to become quite large. For the sake of clarity, I opted for splitting it into different modules, one for each application area. I'm adding components strictly related to an area to the corresponding module, and shared components to an additional common module. All these modules are in turn loaded by a unique main module, that depends on all of these and basically represents the application as a whole.

Now, it turns out that many of the areas need internationalization, so each area's module depends in turn on a translation module to have its string localized. But when I put it all together by means of the main "aggregator" module the translate module ends up with being loaded multiple times, with only one instance actually used.

For instance, let's say my application has the following areas:

- Main dashboard
- Settings
- Documentation
- Support

Corresponding modules are declared as follows:

```js
angular.module('app.mainDashboard', [translate]);
angular.module('app.settings', [translate]);
angular.module('app.settings', [translate]);
angular.module('app.support', [translate]);
```

and the main module looks like this:

```js
angular.module('app.main', [app.mainDashboard, app.settings, app.settings, app.support]);
```

This approach definitely works, but I bet there is a better way to achieve the same result without repeatedly loading the same dependency. Or perhaps my initial module splitting approach is awkward by itself and in turn it leads to this other inconvenient.

Comment: I think you are right in thinking that the split makes things awkward.  In the idea that you are building a SPA there is one application with a load of dependencies.  You don't really gain much in terms of anything by splitting them up in the end anyway as long as each "page" is part of the main application and can be downloaded independently if desired using the getter pattern (i.e. `angular.module('app.main').controller('MyController', ControllerFunction)`)
however, that is just my opinion

Comment: Now what if I suppose each section to be a different application and they all need the common module?

Comment: It sounds like you are more looking for a service than entirely different applications... Think of a module setter as making a new application.  Inside that application you are going to need data access, services, controllers and modules.  Without a pipeline to send/receive data (think API/database) you would not usually 'talk' directly to another application, bringing back the 'pipeline' to interface.  In this case you could do so in the event bus or via events in angular but seems like you are making a bigger deal than it may be worth as there are giant angular apps around already today

Comment: If all of your business logic in all of your factories/controllers needs the `translate` service you could consider using `angular.extend` on a "base" controller, that way your translate service is a prototype method that is only instantiated once.